# Django-crispy-forms: set CSS class for AppendedText parent div

Tags: django, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

**Forms:**

```
class StartEndDateEpayOperatorsForm(forms.Form):

    ...

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(StartEndDateEpayOperatorsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()

        ...

        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            AppendedText('start_date', '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>', active=True, css_class='date'),
            ...
        )
```

**Form HTML:**

[image: Example]

```
        ...
        <div class="input-group">
            <input id="id_start_date" type="text" class="date dateinput form-control" value="2013-10-01" name="start_date"> 
            <span class="input-group-addon active">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
         </div>
        ...
```

In order to use calendar icon as *bootstrap-datepicker* trigger **I need to add new class *date* to the *`<div class="input-group">`***.

How can I achieve it with *django-crispy-forms*?

At the moment the *AppendedText*'s attribute *css_class* aplying to the INPUT element not the parent DIV.

Tnx!

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
self.helper.field_class = 'input-group'
```

this will generate css class with 'input-group' for all fields in this form.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following javascript:

```
 $('.datetimeinput').closest('div').datetimepicker();
```

The closest div would be the 'input-group' div. Bootstrap-datetimepicker will take care of adding the 'date' class to the 'input-group' div.

Answer (score 1):

Building on [Daria's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24319601/3211687), I passed an id (`div_id_start_date_container`) into the container div as follows:

```
Div(AppendedText('start_date', 
                 '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" </span>', active=True),
    css_class='date col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1',
    css_id='div_id_start_date_container'
),
```

I then wrapped this directly via the id instead of relying on the `closest` function.

```
$('#div_id_start_date_container').datepicker({
        format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
        autoclose: true,
        todayHighlight: true
    }
);
```

Note - Crispy forms will create an element named `div_id_start_date` for the form group, so you need to call the outer div something different.